# VBAT Charging Capacitor

Tags: capacitor

I'm sure there's an easy explanation, but I'm stumped.

[image: schematic]

I'm trying to understand Sparkfun's Venus GPS, which can be put into sleep mode by cutting the 3.3v and letting it run from the supercap shown above.
According to my math, the 330 resistor has a voltage drop of almost 3v, leaving no where near 2.9v.
How is this capacitor charged?
Thanks!

Comment: Why do you think the 330 ohms resistor has a voltage drop of 3V ? Maybe the 9mA confuses you ?

Comment: The resistor is just limiting current, your math shouldn't be showing a 3v drop.  Could you show your math?

Comment: Is that all? Is 9mA continuous or a rare peak?

Comment: If it only has a .4v drop, wouldn't the resistance have to be 44.4?  Just using v=ir.

Comment: It certainly doesn't mean the current consumption of the VBAT rail is 9 mA. However 9mA is about what you'd get as short circuit current. The diode drops 3.3V down to 2.9V, and 2.9V/330 is about 9 mA. When the cap's charged, there will be no drop across R3.

Comment: @Tarrinr That 2.9V/9mA callout is just expected maximums for current/voltage on that bus. As voltage rises from 0 to fully charged on the capacitor, the current will drop from 9mA to near zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circuit at DC is simply an open circuit charging the cap.  The caps will thus charge to one diode drop below 3.3V

For low current, the data sheet shows the diode drop to be about 0.7V, so I'd expect the caps to charge to about 2.6V, not 2.9V unless you substitute a Schottky diode.

Comment: The [Venus638FLPx Data Sheet](http://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/GPS/Venus/638/doc/Venus638FLPx_DS_v07.pdf) is certainly lacking in Electrical Characteristics, but if you accept 10uA as typical (Vbat typical current in sleep mode listed <10uA), the [datasheet for the BAS16 diode](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/149/BAS16-104597.pdf) (Figure 3) shows typical Vf at 10uA being around 350mV. A tiny drop across the resistor and Vbat still comes out to around 2.95V which is pretty close to the schematic.